# Set Path for URL Protocol in c#

Tags: c#, path, url-protocol

So I created an URL protocol to run an application with the command arguments.

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.Win32;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace iw4Protocol
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            RegistryKey key = Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey("gameProtocol");

            if (key == null)
            {
                string iw4FullPath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();

                gameProtocol protocol = new gameProtocol();
                protocol.RegisterProtocol(gameFullPath);
            }
            else
            {
                RegistryKey gamepathkey = Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey("gameProtocol");
                string gamepath = gamepathkey.GetValue("gamepath").ToString();

                Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("path",gamepath);



                ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
                startInfo.FileName = @"test.exe";
                startInfo.Arguments = Environment.CommandLine;
                Process.Start(startInfo);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that the program need some files to get launched but it can't load them because the path isn't 'set'.

How I can set this path to launch all these needed files (like `/cd` command)?

Comment: is the Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("path",gamepath); line the one that is throwing the error? If so, isn't it PATH?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cb20e19t.aspx

Comment: @DanielCasserly tried it and changed anything.

Comment: have you debugged this code..? if so please tell us what line you are getting the error and what the value(s) are when you are on that particular line

Comment: The program gets launched but not with the required files.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set the PATH environment variable and use it in your process, add it to the [Environment variables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.environmentvariables(v=vs.110).aspx) but you have to set `UseShellExecute` to false in that case:

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
// set environment
startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
startInfo.EnvironmentVariables["PATH"] += ";" + gamepath;
// you might need more Environment vars, you're on your own here...
// start the exe
startInfo.FileName = @"test.exe";
startInfo.Arguments = Environment.CommandLine;

// added for debugging

startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
startInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;


var p = new Process();
p.StartInfo = startInfo;

using(var sw = new StreamWriter(File.Create("c:\\temp\\debug.txt"))) // make sure C:\temp exist
{
    p.OutputDataReceived += (sender, pargs) => sw.WriteLine(pargs.Data);
    p.ErrorDataReceived += (sender, pargs) => sw.WriteLine(pargs.Data);

    p.Start();
    p.BeginOutputReadLine();
    p.BeginErrorReadLine();

    p.WaitForExit();
}
```

Comment: I hope you realize that we don't have access to your box and you don't provide really helpful information to get an idea what you exactly need. Please read [ask] to get some guidance how to improve your question.

Comment: I mean,for example,my program must have something.txt to works because the program gets some information from there,but the file can't be loaded with the url protocol handler...

Comment: Are you sure you want your complete commandline INCLUDING the current application name and path and not just  `Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();`?

Comment: I've added some debug stuff so you can determine if there are any errors or useful output that better helps you in explaining us what is going wrong.

Comment: "A local variable named 'args' cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning to 'args', which is already used in a 'parent or current' scope to denote something else"